# Npm error 1 on Npm run serve

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I get this error when I type `npm run serve`.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve' ]
2 info using npm@6.1.0
3 info using node@v10.4.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~preserve: frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\project_web\frontend\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\lubomir\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\lubomir\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: CWD: D:\project_web\frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\project_web\frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v10.4.1
19 verbose npm  v6.1.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your package.json file, but as I am using vue, I use command `npm run dev`, not serve. So maybe that’s the problem..